# What is the difference between WSDL and WebIDL?

Tags: web-services, web, wsdl

I know that WSDL describes web services begin with the messages changed between them , ports and data types. About WebIDL (Interface Description Language) I know that describe the object by their interfaces , but how these two can be compared?

Comment: Why are you comparing the two? Should they be comparable just because they share some letters in their names?

Comment: I dont't think so . It was a question and I don't know how to answer.I think they haven't the same purpose. I know about IDL ( that is used in DOM context ). Is WebIDL the same thing with IDL?

Answer (score 0):

**IDL** is a general purpose high level interface description language, easy to create, read and understand for humans. Along with other specifications from OMG IDL forms a solid foundation for developing and deploying a wide range of distributed systems. IDL can be used to describe the set of messages that can be sent to an object. In fact, IDL stands for Interface Definition Language. IDL is a standard from the Object Management Group and is an essential part of the CORBA specification.

**WSDL** is a lower level interface description language which is more difficult to create and understand for humans. Web services clients can get all of the information required to find and access a service in a single WSDL document. The WSDL description of an operation is also simple to convert into XML or HTML to present as a form to a user making it suitable. WSDL stands for the Web Services Description Language and is part of the WS-1 specification from W3C.

**Reference**

IDL and WSDL - A Comparison By Gopi Kumar Bulusu